# eplain macros in CWEB

Tags: pdftex, input, eplain, cweb

I would like to use `eplain` macros in a `CWEB` program, but `eplain` and `cwebmac` seem to conflict in their PDF support. Specifically, they both define `\ifpdf`.

The `cweave` program turns the code below (`mwe.w`) into a `.tex` file with `\input cwebmac` at the top. I can compile with the code as below, by adding `\let\ifpdf\relax` before inputting `eplain` in the original `.w` file. But the resulting PDF has unviewable blank pages in some PDF viewers (the usually reliable `mupdf` on Debian).

If instead, I `cweave mwe` without the top two lines (that is, not inputting eplain at all) and then manually insert `\input eplain` before `\input cwebmac` at the top of `mwe.tex`, then it compiles correctly.

So, **how do I correctly input `eplain` into a CWEB program**?

---

The following program should be saved as `mwe.w`, then run `cweave mwe` and `pdftex mwe`.

```
\let\ifpdf\relax  % non-working workaround
\input eplain

@* Minimal working example.
This is a \.{CWEB} program that uses \.{eplain} macros.

\numberedlist
\li First
\li Second
\endnumberedlist

@p
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    @<Say hello@>@;
    return(0);
}

@ Here is the message we will print.

@<Say hello@>=
printf("Hello, TeX!\n");
```

Comment: For anyone finding this and thinking `eplain` is the only way to do a simple list in `CWEB`, know that you can also use Plain TeX's `\item{1.} First \item{2.} Second`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\relax` is not undefined enough, use

```
\let\ifpdf\undefined  % working workaround
\input eplain
\pdffalse % restore cwebmac definition
```

[image]

Just undefining `\ifpdf` not enough, the two systems define `\ifpdf` for different reasons,
eplain uses it to test for pdftex, but cweave uses `\ifpdftex` for that and uses `\ifpdf` for use with `dvipdf(m)(x)` see:

```
  \ifpdftex\expandafter\xdef\csname curr#1\endcsname{\secno}
    \ifnum#1>0\countB=#1 \advance\countB by-1
      \advancenumber{chunk\the\countB.\expnumber{curr\the\countB}}\fi\fi
  \ifpdf\special{pdf: outline #1 << /Title (\the\toksE) /Dest
```

so if `\ifpdf` is true it does

```
  \special{pdf: outline
```

which is a bad thing to do in pdftex.

Comment: This also produces an unviewable page. When opening with `mupdf` the system gives me the console message `warning: unknown keyword: 'outline'`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner hmm xpdf shows it OK (I added a picture) but I just noticed on the console from where I launched xpdf, I get the warning `$ Syntax Error (271): Unknown operator 'outline'
Syntax Error (271): Unknown operator 'outline' which presumably indicates a problem with the bookmark code
`

Comment: @AndrewCashner Oh I see why, I'll add something to the answer, give me a minute...

Comment: @AndrewCashner try now....

Comment: I realized I could also leave out `\input eplain` command in the `.w` file and instead compile with the command `cweave mwe && pdftex -jobname=mwe "\input eplain \input mwe"`. But your version allows me to do this from within the file.